# UIBarButtonItem will not show when I segue programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigation, segue

I am building an app where I am segueing programmatically from ViewControllerA because it is a list of menu items that each lead to a different VC, so instead of having multiple segues, I instantiate the view controller in code. My issue is that even though I have a Bar button item on my storyboard it will not show in the app.

**View Controller A Menu Model Code:**

```
class PlayerMenu: Hashable {
       let title: String
       let numberOfItems: String
       let menuItemViewController: UIViewController.Type?

       init(title: String, numberOfItems: String, viewController: UIViewController.Type? = nil) {
           self.title = title
           self.numberOfItems = numberOfItems
           self.menuItemViewController = viewController
       }

       func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
           hasher.combine(identifier)
       }

       static func == (lhs: PlayerMenu, rhs: PlayerMenu) -> Bool {
           return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
       }
       private let identifier = UUID()

   }
```

**ViewController A Code**

```
 private lazy var menuItems: [PlayerMenu] = {
        return [
            PlayerMenu(title: "Status", numberOfItems: "Available.", viewController: nil),
            PlayerMenu(title: "Pertinent Medical History", numberOfItems: "", viewController: nil),
            PlayerMenu(title: "Injury / Illness", numberOfItems: "There are no injuries.", viewController: nil),
            PlayerMenu(title: "Allergy", numberOfItems: "There are no allergies.", viewController: AllergyTableViewController.self),
            PlayerMenu(title: "Neurocognitive", numberOfItems: "Unavailable.", viewController: nil),
            PlayerMenu(title: "Medication", numberOfItems: "There are no medications.", viewController: nil),
            PlayerMenu(title: "Immunization", numberOfItems: "There are no immunizations", viewController: nil),
            PlayerMenu(title: "Dictations", numberOfItems: "There are no dictations.", viewController: nil),
            PlayerMenu(title: "Imaging",  numberOfItems: "There is no imaging.", viewController: nil),
            PlayerMenu(title: "Participation", numberOfItems: "Unavailable.", viewController: nil),
            PlayerMenu(title: "Away Game Injury", numberOfItems: "Unavailable.", viewController: nil),

        ]
    }()
```

**ViewControllerA Segue**

```
extension PlayerDashboardViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let menuItem = self.dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) else { return }
        if let viewController = menuItem.menuItemViewController {
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController.init())
            present(navController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

**Storyboard Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing your view controller as you've designed it in your storyboard is because calling `viewController.init()` does not instantiate your view controller from your storyboard. You need to call:

[`UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller)

Or alternatively (only for iOS 13+):

[`UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController(identifier:creator:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/3213989-instantiateviewcontroller)

I recommend instead of storing the view controller type in your `PlayerMenu` class that you store the view controller's storyboard identifier, like so:

```swift
class PlayerMenu: Hashable {
    let title: String
    let numberOfItems: String
    let menuItemViewControllerStoryboardIdentifier: String?

    init(title: String, numberOfItems: String, viewControllerStoryboardIdentifier: String? = nil) {
        self.title = title
        self.numberOfItems = numberOfItems
        self.menuItemViewControllerStoryboardIdentifier = viewControllerStoryboardIdentifier
    }

    [...]
}
```

Then when you want to instantiate your view controller, get a reference to your storyboard (if it's the same as the current view controller's storyboard, then you can just say `self.storyboard`, otherwise create the storyboard directly with [`UIStoryboard.init(name:bundle:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616216-init)):

```swift
extension PlayerDashboardViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let menuItem = self.dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: indexPath),
            let viewControllerStoryboardIdentifier = menuItem.menuItemViewControllerStoryboardIdentifier,
            let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerStoryboardIdentifier) else {
                return
        }

        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        present(navController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Then make sure to give your view controllers identifiers in your storyboard, and create your `PlayerMenu` items like this:

```swift
PlayerMenu(title: "Allergy", numberOfItems: "There are no allergies.", viewControllerStoryboardIdentifier: "AllergyTableViewController (or whatever identifier you give this in your storyboard)")
```